# Select a property parameter (Function) from a Generic Item

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I have a component in which takes in a generic type and a `Func<TItem, string>` to select a property as well as a List of said type called Data. To select the property from the list it's fairly simple: `Data.Select(Property)` and I get a list of said property. However, what I want to do now is not select the list, but select a single item, `TSelected`, from the data (if there are any), where the property is equal to some value I called `tvalue`.

```
[Parameter]
public List<TItem> Data { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public Func<TItem, string> Property { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public TItem Selected { get; set; }

...

private string _value;

[Parameter]
public string Value
{
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        // if it is equals do nothing
        if (string.Equals(_value, value) || value == null)
            return;

        _value = value;

        var selected = Data.Select(Property).FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(value, x));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selected))
        {
            /* Don't know how to select the property from a single TItem */
            Selected = Data.Where( x => x.??? == selected).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually the T prefix indicates a type parameter. When you name your variables `TSelected` and `TValue` it is very confusing.

Comment: I will fix that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Property` func accepts a `TItem` and returns the property that you want, right? So just use it in the where clause.

```
Selected = Data.Where( x => Property(x) == selected).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: awesome worked perfectly. Will accept answer, when the cooldown is done. 7 Mins to go.